Why does postgres sort records by last modification?
I'm developing an application using NestJS, TypeORM, and PostgreSQL.
I've noticed that all my queries are being sorted by the last modification date. I would like to have all my queries sorted by id in descending order (id DESC) by default, without having to specify the sorting manually in every query.
Is there a way to change this default sorting behavior in TypeORM or NestJS?
Thank you!

No, PostgreSQL doesn't sort records when you don't ask for it. From the manual: If sorting is not chosen, the rows will be returned in an unspecified order. The actual order in that case will depend on the scan and join plan types and the order on disk, but it must not be relied on.

Ok, so I think there's no TypeORM config acting here. It's just the way postgres works. I think I would have to provide some default sorting on each query then

Another issue is that there is no guarantee that every table has a column "id". How to sort by a column that isn't there? And how to sort on a query that's using a JOIN and returns the result from different tables and each table has a column "id" ? What do you mean by ORDER BY id DESC; ?

Yes, maybe what I was specting it is a kind of sorting by creation date. Thanks for the help
